# How best to ask advice on how to start programming STM32F?

Tags: discussion

As the title says really. Im struggling to find any specific info such as what software to use and if what I need such as programming environment, hardware and anything in between.

Im worried that if I ask it'll get closed because its asking opinion.

Comment: You might try the [STM32 Forum](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/AllItems.aspx)

Comment: First there are a lot of sub-family variations within this family with different peripheral configuration styles.  Next you have a lot of options from mbed, to the standard peripheral library, to various open solutions to arduino ports to various rtos or even non-rtos systems...

Answer (score 2):

The problem with such a question is that it sounds like an "X-Y" problem: You're asking about a low-level detail, when you haven't described the actual problem you're trying to solve.

The direct answer to "how do I program X" is to ask the manufacturer of X. The underlying questions are "Why did you choose X in the first place?" and/or "Is there some reason that the obvious answer doesn't work for you?". You need to provide enough context to give readers some sense of what you're trying to accomplish.

Such questions are very broad, as well, making them a poor fit for the SE format. Without any idea of how much experience you have with programming and programming environments in general, a reader has no idea where to begin with an answer. Again, context is important.

Comment: In this case, you will probably get very different answers if you ask the *manufacturer* of the STM32, vs. if you look at something like the set of github repositories targeting it.  But yes, goals are a key guide.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to ask that question, chat is a much better format.    Your best approach is to do your due diligence, search for STM32F on and off SE, see what people seem to be using, and try it.  Then, when you hit a snag bringing your toolchain up and running, ask about the specific issue here.

Answer (score -3):

I can't answer the problem exactly, but i can tell you my personal experience. I started by using an STM32F4 discovery board, and used the Kiel IDE. I would recommend using a discovery board so that you don't need to buy external programmers.

Basically look up blog posts and tutorials and see if you can find something similar to what you want to do. There is plenty of information out there.

Comment: Learn how this site works.  This is meta, not the main site.  Here we talk about the site, not about electrical engineering.  Your answer doesn't anwer the question, nor does it belong here.